# Is the space of probability densities on $L^1$ compact with respect to the strong topology?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let ($\Omega, \sigma,\mu$) be finite measure space. Define the space of densities, $\mathcal{D}$,  as follows,

$\mathcal{D}=\{f \in L^1(\Omega):f \geq 0,||f||=1\}$. Then, in general, is $\mathcal{D}$ compact in $L^{1}(\Omega)$?

If not, then does compactness hold for $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^n$, with $\sigma$ as the standard Borel sigma algebra and $\mu$ as the Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: The sequence $f_n = n \mathbb 1_{[0, 1/n]}$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thanks. That was precisely the example I was thinking of.